# Create quadratic matrix with lower triangle as heatmaps and upper triangle character data

Tags: r, panel, heatmap

I have the following (example) data, which I want to plot:
`matrix(c("Variable1",0.4,0.5,"string1","Variable2",0.3,
"string2","string3","Variable3"),ncol=3)`

I want to create heatmaps with the numbers `0.4,0.5,0.3` of the matrix and use the lower triangular:

```
  numeric<- matrix(c(1,0.4,0.5,0.4,1,0.3,0.5,0.3,1),ncol=3)
  require(graphics)
  require(grDevices)
  library(colorRamps)

  library(lattice)
  x <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
  y <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
  grid <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)

   myPanel <- function(x, y, z, ...) { 
   panel.levelplot(x,y,z,...)
   panel.text(x, y, round(z,2),cex=0.578,...)}
  levelplot(numeric,panel=myPanel)
```

On the upper triangle inclusive the diagonal of the heatmap, I want to have characters, with values `"string1", "string2", "string3", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3"` on the same grid position as in the given matrix!

I thought of somehow creating a grid and using the `image()` function of the graphics package to color the numerics, but this doesn't work for me.

Do you have a simple and elegant function, where you just need the given matrix as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [ComplexHeatmap](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap) package by which you can self-define the heatmap body:

First create a symmetrix matrix:

```
set.seed(123)
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 10)
colnames(mat) = letters[1:10]

mat2 = cor(mat)
```

Make clustering and adjust orders for both rows and columns:

```
od = hclust(dist(mat2))$order
mat2 = mat2[od, od]
```

Now we can self-define the heatmap. In following code, `col` controls how to map values to colors.
Since clustering is already applied, we set `cluster_rows` and `cluster_columns` to `FALSE`.
When `type` is set to `none` in `gpar()`, the heatmap is initialized but nothing is added,
then we can use the self-defined function `cell_fun` to add graphic into it.

`cell_fun` will be applied to each small grid in the heatmap.
In `cell_fun`, there are seven arguments:

- `j`: column index in `mat2`
- `i`: row index in `mat2`
- `x`: position on the plot
- `y`: position on the plot
- `w`: width of the current grid
- `h`: height of the current grid
- `col`: filled color for the current grid

Use `Heatmap()` to generate the final heatmap:

```
Heatmap(mat2, col = colorRamp2(c(-1, 0, 1), c("green", "white", "red")),
    cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE,
    heatmap_legend_title = "cor", rect_gp = gpar(type = "none"), 
    cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, w, h, col) {
        if(i > j) {
            grid.rect(x, y, w, h, gp = gpar(fill = col))
        } else if(j == i) {
            grid.text(labels[i], x, y)
        } else {
            grid.text(sprintf("%.2f", mat2[i, j]), x, y)
        }
        grid.rect(x, y, w, h, gp = gpar(fill = NA, col = "black"))
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we have to cluster the correlation matrix?

Comment: And is your heatmap function also possible to change the graphical parameters par(pin=..., ps=...=) only for the upper triangle? For example: I want to create a pairs panel which has on the lower triangle the heatmap (with correlation value) and on the upper triangle some special function creates contour plots with pairs(...,panel=). This special contour-plot function automatically labels the contour lines with height value. I can avoid this labelling by using par(pin=0,ps=c(0,0)), but the size of the correlation values on the lower panel also vanishes. PS:I like the heatmap on Github.

Comment: clustering is just used to put correlated items close to each other.

Comment: You can add any type of graphic into the small grid by self-define `cell_fun`. But it is not easy if you want to add a complicated graphic such as contour-plot because you need to re-implement the contour plot by low-level grid functions. But regarding to your question, if you only want to change parameter for the upper triangle, you can just modify the code in the last `else` code  chunk. Only these code will be executed for the upper triangle.